# WAL archive: FAILED (please make sure WAL shipping is setup)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, barman

I am trying to configure Barman to backup. When I do a `barman check replica` I keep getting:

```
Server replica:
WAL archive: FAILED (please make sure WAL shipping is setup)
PostgreSQL: OK
superuser: OK
wal_level: OK
directories: OK
retention policy settings: OK
backup maximum age: FAILED (interval provided: 1 day, latest backup age: No available backups)
compression settings: OK
failed backups: OK (there are 0 failed backups)
minimum redundancy requirements: FAILED (have 0 backups, expected at least 2)
ssh: OK (PostgreSQL server)
not in recovery: FAILED (cannot perform exclusive backup on a standby)
archive_mode: OK
archive_command: OK
continuous archiving: OK
archiver errors: OK
```

I am using Postgresql 9.6 and barman 2.1; I am not sure as to what the issue is could someone help?
Here is my Barman server configuration:

```
description = "Database backup"
conninfo = host=<db-ip> user=postgres dbname=db
backup_method = rsync
ssh_command = ssh postgres@<db-ip>
archiver = on
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`barman check` tries to confirm that archiving is set up correctly by asserting that there's actually something in the archive.

However, WAL segments are generally only archived once they are filled up, and if your server is idle, then this is never going to happen.

To work around this, Barman provides a command to force a segment switch, wait for the completed WAL to show up, and then archive it immediately:

```
barman switch-xlog --force --archive replica
```

Answer (score 2):

### in brief

Barman's `incoming_wals_directory` and Postgresql.conf's `archive_command` not matched as described in details [here](https://github.com/namgivu/devops-barman-start/blob/master/doc/zz.aftermath-check.md#troubleshooter-for-03---error-wal-archive-failed-please-make-sure-wal-shipping-is-setup)

### details

Another cause is that the **not matched** between

- Barman's `incoming_wals_directory`
- Postgresql.conf's `archive_command`

Bash util to check

```
barman@backup $ barman show-server pg | grep incoming_wals_directory
# output1
# > incoming_wals_directory: /var/lib/barman/pg/incoming

postgres@pg $ cat /etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf | grep archive_command
# output2
# > archive_command = 'rsync -a  %p  barman@staging:/var/lib/barman/pg/incoming/%f'
```

We **must have same path** in :output1 and :output2

Make them matched if they don't and don't forget to restart postgres afterward.